# How to make low poly character, but without edges

Tags: mesh, edges, polycount

I need to find the answer to this question:
I download one character for unity and imported it to the blender to see, how it was made.
I see that is low poly, but there are no edges, and the surface looks very rounded.
I ask this question because I tried to make by myself one character. At first - it has many polygons, but when I try to reduce them with decimate modifiers (for example) - there are many edges. I can't achieve this rounded surface with low poly, such as this character here - low poly and without edges. How it was done?
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're probably looking for "smooth shading".  Select your mesh object, and in object mode, use object->shade smooth from the 3D viewport menu.

Comment: Nathan, thank you, this is what I wanted to do. Now everything is OK with this "smooth shading". I can't understand why this tool is not so popular. When somebody wants to make smooth shading, in YouTube everybody advises making many polygons with Subdivision Surface modifier. This simple tool (smooth shading) is not popular.

Comment: Don't worry, people know about smooth shading.